# RadzenCard is not showing up on my blazor page

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, blazor-server-side, radzen

I have a form that allows users to fill out multiple fields for electronics surplus.it stores the data for all the fields that I have in a RadzenCard using browser session storage then loads the data from session storage in a grid view on the summary page (Page 2) where all the entered information can be reviewed before it is updated in the database. my issue is that my RadzenCard on page one is not showing up at all when I run the app. it shows everything else but not the RadzenCard. here is my code for that page:

```
 @page "/form"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject ContextMenuService ContextMenuService
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>Form</PageTitle>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="h3" style="display: block">Welcome&nbsp; !</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <RadzenDropDownDataGrid TValue="string" ValueProperty="BuildingName" TextProperty="BuildingName" Data="@buildingLists" Placeholder="School Name" Style="width: 100%" AllowSorting="false" AllowSelectAll="false" AllowFiltering="false" ShowSearch="false" PageSize="60">
                    <Columns>
                        <RadzenDropDownDataGridColumn Property="BuildingName" Title="BuildingName" />
                    </Columns>
                </RadzenDropDownDataGrid>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @foreach (var inputData in inputCardData)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- Add this div to control card width -->
                        <RadzenCard Variant="Radzen.Variant.Filled">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <RadzenAutoComplete @bind-Value="inputData.CPSNumber" Placeholder="CPS Number" Style="width: 100%" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <RadzenAutoComplete @bind-Value="inputData.Description" Placeholder="Item Description" Style="width: 100%" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <RadzenDropDownDataGrid TValue="string" ValueProperty="ReasonDescription" TextProperty="ReasonDescription" Data="@reasons" Style="width: 100%" ShowSearch="false" AllowFiltering="false" AllowSorting="false" AllowSelectAll="false" Placeholder="Reason For Surplus" PageSize="10">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <RadzenDropDownDataGridColumn Property="ReasonDescription" Title="ReasonDescription" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </RadzenDropDownDataGrid>
                            </div>
                        </RadzenCard>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<RadzenButton Style="width: 100%; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; height: 40px; display: block; background-color: #005570" Text="Review" Click="FinalizeList"></RadzenButton>

@code {
    [Inject]
    protected Surplus.WASPOService WASPOService { get; set; }

    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.SurplusItemsNew> surplusItemsNews;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList> buildingLists;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reason> reasons;

    // Create a class to hold form data
    public class FormData
    {
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }
    }

    // Create a list to store instances of the form data
    List<FormData> inputCardData = new List<FormData>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        surplusItemsNews = await WASPOService.GetSurplusItemsNews();
        buildingLists = await WASPOService.GetBuildingLists();
        reasons = await WASPOService.GetReasons();
    }

    // Event handler for the "Finalize List" button
    private void FinalizeList()
    {
        // Store the input card data in session data
        var sessionData = inputCardData;
                NavManager.NavigateTo("/summary");
        // You can now use sessionData as needed
        // For example, you can store it in session or pass it to another component or page.
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!!!!!

Comment: you're rendering a card for each `@foreach (var inputData in inputCardData)` but your list is empty? `List<FormData> inputCardData = new List<FormData>();`?

Comment: @RBee the list is empty until the user enters in the fields within that RadzenCard no data can be entered because the card is not showing up on the page. any suggestions on how to fix that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your `inputCardData` list with a new instance of `FormData`

```cs
List<FormData> inputCardData = new List<FormData>(){ new FormData () };
```